# Is there a way to create dynamic migrations in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, controller, migration, laravel-8, database-migration

I want to create the migrations file in dynamic. I developed a product management system and there are multiple stores in the system. I want to create product tables for the store when registering the store.
my table names should like

- store1_products
- store2_products
- store3_products
  ***table structure are same***
  want to create these migration files in store create function

I all ready tried schema function on controller .

```
    Schema::create($tableName, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('email')->index();
            $table->string('token');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

It created the table on the database but I want to create the migration file too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to just create a one table for the store and one table for the product. Then the product table must have a column that identify what store it is belongs to.

Stores Table.

```
Schema::create('stores', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('store_name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Products Table

```
Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('product_name')->unique();
    $table->unsignedFloat('price');
    $table->unsignedTinyInteger('quantity');

    $table->foreignId('store_id')
        ->constrained('stores')
        ->cascadeOnDelete();

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Then you can refer to [Laravel Eloquent Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships) to know how to define their relationship.

Just make sure that you have model for them

Comment: yes, that's the method that I used in previous projects. but this time client wants to maintain the table separately for the store

Comment: So if the they have 100 stores then they want to have a 1 separate for each store ?

Comment: If that's what you want then. You need to create a `custom stub file` for your `Schema` then create a `custom command`  like this `php artisan custom_command:create store1_products` that you will call each time you will add a new store. Then that command will generate the already build migration file.

Comment: thank you buddy that's helpful for me